# import error for pip install for python 3.6 packges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

[image]

I just started playing around with python 3.6 on windows, I created a virtual enviorment for my script and in it I ran the command `pip install lxml`.

The package was downloaded and I can now import it in my script but when trying to import `lxml.etree` I get an error saying the etree is not there.

when running the following:

```
import lxml;
print(lxml.__file__);
```

The output is: 
`my_virtual_env_path\lib\site-packages\lxml\__init__.py`

this is what is printed when installing lxml with pip in my virtual env:

```
(env) c:\test>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
Using cached lxml-4.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.2.0
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstall, doesn't solve it.

`lxml` is imported sucessfully, but `lxml.etree` is unrecognized

This is the structure of the imported lxml in my virtual enviorment:

[image]

What is the problem and how to solve it? Is it something that has to do with the installation?

Comment: Just a nitpicky thing: The semicolons at the end of your lines are unnecessary.  That might be a syntax error under certain circumstances, but they don't seem to be here.

Comment: Has the installation succeeded? Did you look inside that folder? Does `site-packages\lxml\etree` exist?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem.  The code you posted works...

Comment: try the install with with pip3 instead of pip

Comment: I posted it to give more information, the problem is that there is not etree in the lxml package I installed using pip. `import lxml.etree` is unrecognized

Comment: Side note: `;` is not needed. Python allows it as an alternative statement delimiter for convenience (and not in all statements) but the primary delimiter is the newline.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your IDE. The file containing the module is present in the package -- it's `<venv>\lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`.

If you run your script directly from the virtualenv, it should work fine.

You should probably configure your IDE to use your virtualenv, not just your py3.6 installation.